# Using Grepl with an ifelse statement to Label a column

Tags: r, grepl

I have a a data frame that contains variables of 3 different types, and I want to use grepl (or maybe grep) to determine which type of variable it is using keywords, and then put the type in a new column

i.e.

```
col1       col2
meat       food  
dogs       animal
cat        animal
cake       food
orange     food
books      misc
```

I have tried using both an if and an ifelse, but to no avail. One thing I have tried (bar any trivial syntax errors):

```
    df$col2 <- ifelse(grepl("apple", df$col1, ignore.case = TRUE) "food"
               ifelse(grepl("cat", df$col1, ignore.case = TRUE) "animal", 
               misc)
```

I either pop a "condition has length >1" or every entry in the new column is just one value repeated

Comment: Check the `misc` length `ifelse` require all the arguments to be same length.  If you have length of 1, it gets recycled and if it is greater than 1 and not equal to the column number of row, there is a warning with length > 1

Comment: Looks like you're missing some commas and parentheses.

Comment: @akrun, that's not right.  `ifelse()` uses the usual recycling rules if the arguments aren't the same length.  The first argument (the logical test) determines the length of the result.

Comment: You should show us the real code you used on some real data (not necessarily your original data, but something similar to show what you tried).

Comment: @user2554330. OP showed a warning, it is related to unequal lengths.  Also, please check the `?ifelse`. It says `If yes or no are too short, their elements are recycled. yes will be evaluated if and only if any element of test is true, and analogously for no.`

Comment: This should get you the result: df<-df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(col2 = ifelse(grepl("apple", col1, ignore.case = T), "food",
                              ifelse(grepl("cat", col1, ignore.case = T), "animal", "misc")))

Comment: @akrun:  the warning shown doesn't come from `ifelse`, it comes from `if`.  We don't have the real code here.  And the help page says exactly what I said:  the usual recycling rules are used.